# Visual boundary vs. ideal boundary of hyperbolic manifolds?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

I apologize in advance if this is elementary; I have very little experience with hyperbolic manifolds, but I'm using hyperbolic manifolds for part of a current project.

Given a discrete torsion-free subgroup of isometries acting on hyperbolic space $\Gamma \hookrightarrow \mathrm{Isom}(\mathbb{H}^n)$, then $\Gamma$ also acts on the boundary sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ of hyperbolic space. As I understand it, we just take the ray projectivization of Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}^{n,1}$ (or the full projectivization; doesn't matter), and then hyperbolic space can be realized as the north or south polar "cap" of the projective sphere, and the boundary of hyperbolic space is the projectivization of the light cone.

For any point $x \in \mathbb{H}^n$, the set $L(\Gamma) := \overline{\Gamma x} \cap \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is called the **limit set** of $\Gamma$, and $O(\Gamma) = \mathbb{S}^{n-1} - L(\Gamma)$ is called the **ordinary set** of $\Gamma$. Then Theorem 12.6.5 in Ratcliffe states that
$$\overline{M}= \left( \mathbb{H}^n \cup O(\Gamma) \right)/\Gamma$$ 
is a manifold with boundary $\partial M =O(\Gamma)/\Gamma$.

This provides a means of compactifying a complete connected hyperbolic manifold $M \cong \mathbb{H}^n/\Gamma$ by attaching what Ratcliffe calls the **ideal boundary** $O(\Gamma)/\Gamma$.

> **Question 1:** If $O(\Gamma)/\Gamma$ is non-empty, under what conditions is $\overline{M}$ a *smooth* manifold with boundary?

If I recall correctly, quotients of smooth manifolds with boundary do not necessarily have a unique smooth structure. If am I wrong and they indeed do, could someone point me to a reference?

In Bridson & Haefliger's text, they describe a different notion of compactification by attaching a **visual boundary** $\partial M$ to $M$. Given a complete connected Riemannian $n$-manifold of non-positive sectional curvature, take a point $x \in M$ and define $\partial M$ to be the set of geodesics defined by vectors in the unit sphere in $T_x M$. When $\overline{M}= M \cup \partial M$ is given the so-called cone topology, the topology restricts to the usual one on $M$, and they state in Example II.8.11 that the topology of $\partial M$ is that of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

> **Question 2:** What is the relationship between visual compactification of a hyperbolic manifold and compactification by attaching the ideal boundary?

I suspect that that these two notions of compactification differ, because it seems strange that $O(\Gamma)/\Gamma$ would always be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^n$.

Comment: Regarding question 1, $\overline{\mathbb{H}}^n \cup \partial\mathbb{H}^n$ is naturally a smooth ball on which the action of the isometry group of $\mathbb{H}^n$ extends smoothly (you can see this by embedding into the projective space). So $\mathbb{H}^n \cup O(\Gamma)$ is naturally a smooth submanifold with boundary on which the action of $\Gamma$ is smooth, and this smooth structure descends to give a natural smooth structure on $\overline M$.

Comment: Something is wrong in question 2. The statement that the topology of $\partial M$ is that of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is true in the simply connected case, but not more generally.

Comment: Just a precision on Lee Mosher's first comment: it is not well-known, but easy to see that there is a multiplicity of non-differentiably conjugate ways to make the action of isometries on the compactification of hyperbolic space smooth. Investigating these smooth actions was my first research topic, see arXiv:math/0506135. So there is a multiplicity here, but it does not come from the quotient, it comes from the multiplicity before taking the quotient.

Comment: As Lee Mosher has already mentioned, you forget an important part of the definition of the visual compactification: the manifold $M$ has to be simply connected.

Comment: in that case visual compactification isn't very useful for hyperbolic manifolds, right? Since the only complete, simply connected hyperbolic manifold is $\mathbb{H}^n$.